# Why 100% height doesn't work

Tags: css

[This is my website.](http://foog.org/bare2/)
I create Wrapper div.

```
#wrapper {
background: url(../img/bg.png) repeat;
width:100%;
height:100%;}
```

But it doesn't work completely. Wrapper doesn't include bottom. Why ?

Comment: Definitely seems to be full height to me

Comment: @DanGreen please look again http://www.foog.org/bare2/

Comment: it is width: 100% in Safari. Should be the same in other browsers

Comment: Do you mean the dotted overlay is not 100%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean not 100% is the dotted background, I've come out with a solution by changing the height property in CSS:

```
height: auto;
```

This will fix it somehow. Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you very much :) I cant give vote your answer sorry, I haven't got 15 reputation.